# data loading into a table having composite primary key in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When i am trying to create a composite primary key in redshift the create table statement successfully executes though when i try loading in the table  , the data loading fails stating that the Multiple primary keys are not allowed.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with multiple primary keys?

Comment: The thing is that we are trying to migrate from Teradata to Redshift and our schema conversion tool is replicating all what lies in TD. The conversion successfully completed but the error happened in data loading part .

Comment: OK well use a different tool or manually intervene. You really need to take a step back and consider the best approach for each table rather than rely on automation.

Comment: I agree with u that we in rs the concept doesnt hold much of a value . Though my only question is that if redshift gives a scope of adding composite primary key why does it fail while loading into a table with composite primary key .

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift does not make heavy use of Primary Keys. For example, **it does not enforce uniqueness** — that is the responsibility of your application.

Primary Keys *are* used to optimize queries.

See: [Defining Constraints - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html)

So, unless you have a particular need, it's probably easier to avoid primary keys during the data-loading phase. You can always optimize later.